# Getting GitHub API token via CLI, for CLI

Tags: github-api

We used to be able to create GitHub personal access tokens via a request to `api.github.com/authorizations` with the username, password, and specifying the token’s scope. That functionality has been deprecated [as of November 13, 2020](https://developer.github.com/changes/2020-02-14-deprecating-oauth-auth-endpoint/).

It seems nothing took its place. They recommend the [web application flow](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/developers/apps/authorizing-oauth-apps#web-application-flow), which makes no sense if you’re building a CLI tool.

Rather than asking people to go to https://github.com/settings/tokens to manually create a new token, is there an alternative which works by not having to leave the CLI?

Answer (score 0):

For that use case you should consider using "Device Flow". Documented [here](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/developers/apps/authorizing-oauth-apps#device-flow).

Comment: “Step 2: Prompt the user to enter the user code in a browser”. The question specifically asks for “an alternative which works by not having to leave the CLI”.

Comment: Github specifically states that you should use this flow for CLIs... You don't leave it really as it continues to run until authentication is done. DF is designed to complete the authentication on a separate channel. Entering credentials on a CLI is somewhat problematic for security reasons. Also, this flow is usually complemented with 'offline_access` (I have not checked in GH supports it). This means you can use refresh tokens afterwards, with *no* user interaction. The overall experience is similar to the Heroku CLI (if you are familiar with it)